# add primary row to query results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How do I add a primary row  to a query result in MSSQL 2005. Here's an example of what I need to return?

Here are the two queries

query 1

```
select product_id, sku from products
```

query 2

```
select product_id, sku from childproducts
```

The results should look like this. (without the query 1, of course)

```
    row 1: products.product_id, products.sku   (comes from one parent table)
    row 2: childproducts.product_id, childproducts.sku   (comes from child table)
    row 3: childproducts.product_id, childproducts.sku   (comes from child table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them using UNION ALL, e.g.

```
select 1 as Sorter, product_id, sku from products
UNION ALL
select 2, product_id, sku from childproducts
ORDER BY Sorter, product_id
```

Notice I added the Sorter column to make the parent set appear before the child products.  If you had to exclude it, but still show them in that order:

```
select product_id, sku
from (
    select 1 as Sorter, product_id, sku from products
    UNION ALL
    select 2, product_id, sku from childproducts
) X
ORDER BY Sorter, product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add a primary key that maintains the ordering of the rows, so the children immediately follow the parent.  The following code does this using `row_number()` to assign the new id:

```
select row_number() over (order by parentproduct_id, isparent desc) as newid,
       product_id, sku
from ((select product_id, sku, product_id as parentproduct_id, 1 as isparent
       from productions
      ) union all
      (select product_id, sku, parentproduct_id, 0 as isparent
       from childproducts
      )
     ) p
```

If you don't actually want an id in the data but just want the sort order, then add this:

```
order by parentproduct_id, isparent desc
```